# I cannot add language data to tesseract

Tags: ubuntu, ocr, tesseract, windows-subsystem-for-linux

### Purpose

I want to do Chinese ocr by using tesseract.
If I want to use Chinese ocr, I need to add the traineddata.
Then, I think there are two ways to add traineddata, by using a command
`sudo apt install tesseract-ocr-chi-sim` 
or
by downloading from
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/blob/master/chi_sim.traineddata

With the method of installing from sudo apt install, Chinese data was correctly added and ocr was successfully completed.
However, when I tried the latter method, it didn't work even if I tried many times.

The reason I want to try the latter method is that I think that the latter may have higher accuracy of ocr than the data installed from sudo apt install, and I really want to try it.
Do you know why I can't do ocr?

---

### Error massage

When I add data in the latter way, I got the following error.

```
> $ tesseract 0.jpeg output -l chi_sim Error opening data file
> /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/chi_sim.traineddata Please make
> sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your
> "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language 'chi_sim' Tesseract
> couldn't load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.
```

---

### What I did

In both cases, the traineddata of tesseract is as follows.

```
$ tesseract --list-langs
List of available languages (5):
chi_sim
chi_tra
eng
jpn
osd
```

The traineddata is contained in /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/, so there is no mistake in where to put the data.

```
/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata$ ls
chi_sim.traineddata  configs          jpn.traineddata    osd.traineddata  tessconfigs
chi_tra.traineddata  eng.traineddata pdf.ttf
```

The error that appeared this time was due to the TESSDATA_PREFIX path, so I tried to execute it through the path in the following two ways, but the same error also appeared here.

First, I added the following text to ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile.

```
export TESSDATA_PREFIX=/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/
```

Second, I excute ocr as follows.

```
tesseract 0.jpeg output -l chi_sim --tessdata-dir /usr/share/tesse
ract-ocr/4.00/tessdata
```

---

### Version of tools

```
$ tesseract --version
tesseract 4.0.0-beta.1
leptonica-1.75.3
libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.2) : libpng 1.6.34 : libtiff 4.0.9 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 0.6.1 : libopenjp2 2.3.0

Found AVX2
Found AVX
Found SSE
```

After that, I changed the version of tesseract to tesseract 5.0.0-alpha and tried it, but the result was exactly the same.

From the error message, I think it is a problem with the TESSDATA_PREFIX path. Is there a mistake in the way to add the path? Or, are there any other reasons?

Comment: Have you verified you have permissions to that file with your user (ie: `chmod`)?

Comment: I am very sorry to be late to reply your advice. Thank you for your advice very much. As you said, I have not verified permissions to files. I am going to try to verify them. Thanks to your advice, I got to know the reason I cannot use the files. I appreciate your help!